# Why does offsetWidth return undefined as the width of svg?

Tags: javascript, svg, width

```js
let svg = document.querySelector("svg");
console.log(svg.getBoundingClientRect().width);
console.log(svg.offsetWidth);
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 700 300">
  <path d="M0 300c150 0 50-300 200-300l300 0c150 0 50 300 200 300 h-700" />
</svg>
```

Why does `getBoundingClientRect()` return the width of the svg but not `offsetWidth`?

I can just ignore it and go with `getBoundingClientRect()`, but I want to know the reason for why this happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because [`SVGElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGElement) doesn't have an `offsetWidth` property. (MDN lists it [only in the compat table] as "non-standard" and shows basically no browser support for it.) Any time you request a property from an object that the object doesn't have, you get `undefined`.

Remember that `SVGElement` instances are not [`HTMLElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) instances.

Comment: As for *why* `SVGElement` doesn't have an `offsetWidth` property, um, dunno. :-)

Comment: And `getBoundingClientRect()` can give the width because it calculates the width *after* the element has rendered? (which I think makes it possible to obtain the width of any element)

Comment: @BookOfFlames - [`getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) is a method of [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element), which is the base class (well, base interface) of both `SVGElement` and `HTMLElement`. So it applies to both.